# Get the last N words in a string

Tags: php, preg-match, delimited

I am trying to get the last few words in a string.
For the last word, I am using this:

```
$string = "Hallo dies ist ein extrem langer Text den ich gern gekuerz haette, leider bin ich selbst zu doof daf&uuml;r und mach hier einen test.";

$pattern = '/[^ ]*$/';

preg_match($pattern, $string, $result);

echo "<br>The last word is:------ ". $result[0] ." ---------<br>";
```

It works fine, but I need the flexibility to get, say, the last 3 words.

I do not know how to change the pattern.

Comment: Do you want the last three words as a single string, or the last three words as three separate elements?  Your [mcve] is not crystal clear on the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That will do the job

```
$pattern = '/(([^ ]*)\s+([^ ]*)\s+([^ ]*))$/';
```

**[Example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Txh2ha)**

or

```
$pattern = '/((([^ ]*)[\s.]+){3})$/';
```

**[Example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/bQ6PR2)**

Comment: how I see you just copied the pattern-part three times.
Is there also a possibility to do it with a parameter like {3} ?

Comment: something wrong?
Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier '$' in /www/htdocs/w00fcda7/js/1.php on line 13

Comment: When pasting I forgot to put `/` around. See updated answer and example.

Comment: without the $ it seems to work.
It gives this array: Array ( [0] => Hallo dies ist [1] => ist [2] => ist )

Comment: so it found three matches.
can you give me a short explanation what is the pattern doing

Comment: by that way. Did I mentioned that it gives the first three words, not the last ones ...

Comment: I changed the pattern to:
$pattern = '/((([^ ]*)[\s.]+){3})$/';

Comment: peterm: where is the tricky setting that it starts from the end?

Comment: @hamburger It's the anchor `$` that matches the end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably better off using `explode` on the string, something like this:

```
$string = 'Hello, my name is Jordan Doyle';
$string_array = explode(' ', $string);
echo end($string_array);
```

Example output:

```
root@upstairslinux:~# php example.php
Doyle

root@upstairslinux:~#
```

Here's a function to get a specified amount of lines...

```
<?php
function get_last_words($amount, $string)
{
    $string_array = explode(' ', $string);

    return array_slice($string_array, count($string_array) - $amount);
}

$string = 'Hello, my name is Jordan Doyle';
var_dump(get_last_words(3, $string));
```

Example output:

```
root@upstairslinux:~# php example.php
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "is"
  [1]=>
  string(6) "Jordan"
  [2]=>
  string(5) "Doyle"
}

root@upstairslinux:~#
```

Comment: I'am working with this:

$length = 3;

$shortStart = implode(' ',array_slice(str_word_count($string,1),0,$length));
echo "<br>shortened:------ ". $shortStart ." ---------<br>";

$shortened = implode(' ',array_slice(str_word_count($string,1),count(str_word_count($string,1))-$length));
echo "<br>shortened:------ ". $shortened ." ---------<br>";

It works fine but I'am looking for pattern now, to built in for a function.

Comment: Edited my post to include this for you.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

```
   $patterns = '/\b[a-zA-Z]*\b/';
```

and use preg_match_all to match all occurences

```
  preg_match_all($patterns, $string, $result);

  $string = "Hallo dies ist ein extrem langer Text den ich gern gekuerz haette, leider bin ich selbst zu doof daf&uuml;r und mach hier einen test.";

 preg_match_all($patterns, $string, $result);

 foreach($result[0] as $value){
  echo "$value ";
 } 



for($length = count($result[0]), $i = 1; $i < 4; $i++){
       $offset = $length - $i;
       echo $result[0][$offset];
     }
```

the above snippet extracts the last 3 words

Comment: sorry using this pattern gives this:
The last word is:------ st. ---------
thats the last three letters ...

Comment: sorry . . .I misunderstood the question . . . . you can use \b to match word boundaries and retrieve any number of words from the resulting array

Comment: this gives only the first word back ..
and do not match all the words in the line.

Answer (score -1):

It's probably better off using explode on the string, something like this:

```
<?php 
$cate = 'category-node-25';
$cateId = explode('-', $cate);
echo end($cateId);
?>
```

Output --> 25.

Answer (score -1):

Use preg_match to look for a word defined by the standard word-boundaries (as opposed to just spaces).

```
if (preg_match('/\w+\s*$/', $string, $matches)) {
    $last_word = $matches[0];
    echo $last_word;
} else {
    echo "No match found";
}
```